# Delete a item from linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

How can I delete a Item from a linked list in c.

```
typedef struct
{
    int n;
    struct item *nexI;

} item;


#define na 1000
int n, j;
```

I have in my main:

```
item * list[na];

n = 5;

for(j = 0; j < na; j++)
    remove_elem(list, n, j);
```

now my function remove_elem:

```
void remove_elem(item * list[], int n, int pos)
{
    int i;
    item * aux;
    item * sec;


    aux = list[pos]->nexI;

    if(aux == NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        sec = (item *)aux->nexI;

        if(aux->n == n)
        {
        list[pos]->nexI = sec;
            return;
        free(aux);
        }

        while(sec != NULL)
        {

            if(sec->n == n)
            {
                aux->nexI = sec->nexI;
                free(sec);
                return;
            }
        aux = (item *) aux->nexI;
        sec = (item *) sec->nexI;
        }
    }
```

}

but this code is giving me a segmentation fault and i cant notice why, can u figure it what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Dupe a million times. Search for "delete from linked list".

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? This will tell you _where_ the crash happens.

Comment: And where does your debugger show the segmentation fault occurring? And what were the variable values at that point?

Comment: debug one item at a time. you are getting segmentation because you are accessing a memory address not valid for access, which means there is an edge case you probably didn't handle well. maybe there's off-by-one index problem in ur code. try that. or deleting a pointer that isn;t supposed to be deleted.

Comment: segmentation fault occures when i call this func in main but is a but confused i used gdb but i didnt undertand much...

Comment: if you don;t udnerstand gdb for now, okay, just use printf or combination of that and see what you are deleting. you are trying to purge the entire list (or a bunch of items from the list). See at which point it fails. Did it fail as soon as first one is deleted? or middle or at the last element? then you can narrow down an edge case.

Comment: When the crash happens in gdb, you will get a line stating what file, function and line the crash happens. However, you first have to compile your code with the `-g` flag to gcc to include debug info. Also, if you use the `bt` command in gdb you will get a function call trace, so you see how you ended up there.

Comment: And this compiles? But where are you defining `struct item`? (And no, it's not with the typedef: your `typedef struct { int n; struct item *nexI;} item;` defines `item` as a typedef for an anonymous struct containing an `int` and a pointer to a `struct item`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going strictly by your code, I would wager a guess that it's about uninitialized pointers.

First when you declare your array of pointers, you need to initialize all pointers to `NULL`:

```
item * list[na] = { NULL };
```

Then you should check for `NULL` pointers in all your functions:

```
void remove_elem(item * list[], int n, int pos)
{
    if (list[pos] == NULL)
        return;

    /* ... */
}
```

And of course, when you allocate a new node to put in the list, you of course have to set the `nexI` pointer to `NULL` as well, or checks like `if(aux == NULL)` will not work.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply! In the exact moment you gave me that answer i understood that missing case. Such a distraction. Thanks again, now everything is working just fine! :)